# В режиме Debug программа работает правильно, но в release не работает?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Всем здарова, проблема такая: когда компилишь код в профиле debug она работает нормально, но в профиле release текст не выводится, но основную суть выполняет (меняет тайтл консоли).
Что делать?
Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

wchar_t OriginalTitle[5000];
wchar_t MyTitle[5000] = L"Супир тайтэль (я нассаль на двигатэль)";

int main(void)
{
    _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L"ru_RU.UTF-8");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
    GetConsoleOriginalTitleW(OriginalTitle, 5000);
    wprintf(L"Я получил оригинальный тайтл!\nВот: '%ls'\n\n", OriginalTitle);
    SetConsoleTitleW(MyTitle);
    wprintf(L"Я сменил оригинальный тайтл на: '%ls'!\n", MyTitle);
    system("pause");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Вы запускаете отладчик для приложения, которое скомпилировано в релиз. Попробуйте запустить ваше приложение не в отладчике, а штатным способом.

Comment: Сетлокале два раза то зачем? и там в виндах по другому кодовые страницы называются, посмотрите документацию.

Comment: Помогло _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L"Russian"); и setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L"Russian");
> setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
> ```
>
> И всё заработало)